# using http with axios return 400 with request it works

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

I use the following code using [request](https://github.com/request/request#readme) which works as expected, got http response **200**

```
var request = require('request');

var auth
var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://oauth2.k.de.com/oauth2/token',
    'headers': {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic NGViMTE2ODctZTNjNi00NDUyLTgwNjgtMzhiOjJDR2lJd0hxOFFx==',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    form: {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'scope': 'app:read'
    }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    let body = JSON.parse(response.body);

 ….
```

Now I need to convert it to [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) as request been deprecated but it’s not working for me ( I got http 400 response )

```
const axios = require('axios').default;


axios({
    method: 'post',
    'url': 'https://oauth2.k.de.com/oauth2/token',
    data: {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'scope': 'app:read'
    },
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': 'Basic NGViMTE2ODctZTNjNi00NDUyLTgwNjgtMzhiOjJDR2lJd0hxOFFx==',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}).then(function (response: any) {
    console.log("Head With Authentication :" + response);
}).catch(function (error: any) {
    console.log("Post Error : " + error);
});
```

Any idea why with request library with the **exact same data** it works (http response 200) and in axios I **got 400** ? 
In request I put the grant_type etc in **form** and in axios in **data**, this is the only diffrencace I see, any idea?

This is the error I got

**Request failed with status code 400**

Should I use other rest libary if it cannot be done via `axios` ?

Comment: You've put the option element "url" in as string. I am not at my IDE, so I cannot verify if that's the problem.

Comment: grant_type and scope is not part of data. you should append them to headers I guess

Comment: @DirkR - should I try to change something?

Comment: @ilkerkaran - I've tried to put it on the header and got the same error, Request failed with status code 400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, you might want to check this: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362

The problem is, because of axios interceptors, your `Content-Type` header is disappearing. If you have access and can change the backend, you can make it work with another header and set it on your client code. Otherwise if your code is working in a browser, you can try using `URLSearchParams` as suggested [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format).

Comment: so If I cannot change the BE , I cannot use axios ?

Comment: Yes. I checked the GitHub issues and axios guys won’t change their library. If you don’t want to change the backend, you can consider using another client library instead of axios.

Comment: Thanks for this! do you have any suggestion which may work for my use case?

Comment: I'm using `fetch`, but it's only for browsers, so it won't work in nodejs backend: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API